# d3 directed graph, how it works

Tags: d3.js, graph

I'm trying to insert a d3 directed graph( [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347) ) to a Thorax( super type of Backbone ) view. I was able to do it but still have questions on way it is working(d3 code).

1. First we create the force layout passing nodes and edges

   ```
    var force = d3.layout.force()
   .nodes(nodes)
   .links(links)
   .size([width, height])
   .linkDistance(150)
   .charge(-500)
   .on('tick', tick)
   ```

   Does this create the graph actually?
2. What does these two lines do

   ```
   this.path = this.svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('path');
   this.circle = this.svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('g');
   ```

   append a `svg:g` element to `svg` element. OK I get it. but with selectAll. I don't get it. Is paths already there? created by the force layout?
3. `this.path = this.path.data(this.links);` What does this do? I really have no idea?
4. Then append paths.

   ```
    this.path.enter().append('svg:path')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .style('marker-start', function (d) {
         return d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : '';
    })
    .style('marker-end', function (d) {
         return d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : '';
    });
   ```
5. Then goes nodes. Starting like

   ```
    this.circle = this.circle.data(this.nodes, function (d) {
        return d.id;
    });
   ```
6. Create a group first I think because to keep circle and label text together

   ```
   var g = this.circle.enter().append('svg:g');
   ```
7. Now we create the circle.

   ```
   g.append('svg:circle')
       .attr('class', 'node')
       .attr('r', 12)
       .style('stroke', _.bind(function (d) {
            return d3.rgb(this.colors(d.id)).darker().toString();
       }, this))
       .classed('reflexive', function (d) {
            return d.reflexive;
       })
   ```
8. Append label text to the save group.

   ```
   g.append('svg:text')
       .attr('x', 0)
       .attr('y', 4)
       .attr('class', 'id')
       .text(function (d) {
            return d.id;
       });
   ```

So I kind of get the overall idea of what is happening. But not exactly. Appreciate any help understanding better what is happening where.

Comment: You should really have a look at the d3 presentation available [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/d3/workshop/). It'll answer a lot of the questions you asked.

Comment: I know. Issue is limited time :(. Anyway reading about d3.
BTW figure out about 2nd point.